# Proyecto Instalador visual estudio 2017 error sql_ssms

Tags: windows-forms

estoy intentando crear un instalador para una aplicación, en la cual utilizo .net framework 4.7, con ORM nhibernate 5.2... el problema que tengo es cuando intento generar el instalador, intenta configurar sql server manager studio 2008 R2  y no lo encuentra... lo extraño es que no tengo ninguna referencia a mssql server en mi aplicación, alguien tiene idea que puede estar pasando... [image: Captura de el error]

Comment: A lo mejor tienes algo en las 'condiciones de inicio' del proyecto setup. Es el último icono de los que te aparecen en el explorador de soluciones (en tu pantallazo no se ve, tendrás que pulsar sobre las comillas)

Comment: hola gracias por responder lo resolví  registrando las dll C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll como indica en este comentario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040970/how-do-i-stop-sql-server-2008-r2-trying-to-install-some-package-when-i-build-my

Answer (score 0):

la solución esta en este comentario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040970/how-do-i-stop-sql-server-2008-r2-trying-to-install-some-package-when-i-build-my hay que registar la dll  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSI Tools\mergemod.dll

Comment: agrega el comando  que ejecutastes!